# C++ CUDA and libpng linking error

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, cuda, libpng

**Solved:** see my comment below

I've been working on a GPU fractal generator, and have been using CUDA to access the GPU, and libpng to produce output images. I'm running OSX 10.7.4, Cuda release 4.2, V0.2.1221, libpng15 (1.5.11 I think)

**The first version** (really messy and hacky) of the code had only one source file, 
    GPUkernel.cu, which had functions to calculate the fractal using the CUDA library, and also generate the png with libpng. This compiled fine with the command

```
all:    src/GPUkernel.cu
        nvcc -o base src/GPUkernel.cu -lpng15 -lz
```

which produced the executable base, and everything ran fine.

**The New Version:**

Now, to try and make the code more manageable as this project gets bigger, I have split the source into two files, 
    GPUkernel.cu 
and 
    GPUfractal.cpp
. 
    GPUkernel.cu 
holds all CUDA GPU functions, and 
    GPUfractal.cpp 
holds the main() and libpng functions.

I get some problems when I try to compile this code, to do with different architectures that libpng and CUDA work with (I think). My makefile is:

```
CUDA_INSTALL_PATH ?= /Developer/GPU\ Computing/CUDALibraries/common

ARCH=-arch i386 -arch x86_64

CXX := g++
CC := gcc
LINK := g++ -fPIC $(ARCH)
NVCC := nvcc -ccbin /usr/bin

# Includes
INCLUDES = -I. -I$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/inc -I/usr/local/cuda/include 

# Common flags
COMMONFLAGS += $(INCLUDES)
NVCCFLAGS += $(COMMONFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS += $(COMMONFLAGS)
CFLAGS += $(COMMONFLAGS)

LIB_CUDA := -L$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/lib `libpng-config --cflags --ldflags`

OBJS = GPUkernel.cu.o GPUfractal.cpp.o
TARGET = base
LINKLINE = $(LINK) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIB_CUDA)

.SUFFIXES: .c .cpp .cu .o

%.c.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

%.cu.o: %.cu
    $(NVCC) $(NVCCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

%.cpp.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(TARGET): $(OBJS) Makefile
    $(LINKLINE)
```

And here's my terminal output:

```
pikachu:GPUfractal tom$ make
nvcc -ccbin /usr/bin -I. -I/Developer/GPU\ Computing/CUDALibraries/common/inc -I/usr/local/cuda/include  -c GPUkernel.cu -o GPUkernel.cu.o
ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_00000847_00000000-2_GPUkernel.ptx, line 105; warning : Double is not supported. Demoting to float
g++ -I. -I/Developer/GPU\ Computing/CUDALibraries/common/inc -I/usr/local/cuda/include  -c GPUfractal.cpp -o GPUfractal.cpp.o
GPUfractal.cpp: In function ‘int renderImage(int*, float*, int, int, std::string, bool, int)’:
GPUfractal.cpp:180: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
GPUfractal.cpp:232: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
g++ -fPIC -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -o base GPUkernel.cu.o GPUfractal.cpp.o -L/Developer/GPU\ Computing/CUDALibraries/common/lib `libpng-config --cflags --ldflags`
ld: warning: ignoring file GPUfractal.cpp.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
  "_cudaGetLastError", referenced from:
      calculateFractal(int*, float*, int, int, float, float, float, float, int, bool, float, float)in GPUkernel.cu.o
  "_cudaGetErrorString", referenced from:
      calculateFractal(int*, float*, int, int, float, float, float, float, int, bool, float, float)in GPUkernel.cu.o
  "_cudaMemset", referenced from:
      calculateFractal(int*, float*, int, int, float, float, float, float, int, bool, float, float)in GPUkernel.cu.o
  "_cudaConfigureCall", referenced from:
      calculateFractal(int*, float*, int, int, float, float, float, float, int, bool, float, float)in GPUkernel.cu.o
  "_cudaMemcpy", referenced from:
      calculateFractal(int*, float*, int, int, float, float, float, float, int, bool, float, float)in GPUkernel.cu.o
  "_cudaFree", referenced from:
      calculateFractal(int*, float*, int, int, float, float, float, float, int, bool, float, float)in GPUkernel.cu.o
  "___cudaRegisterFatBinary", referenced from:
      __sti____cudaRegisterAll_44_tmpxft_00000847_00000000_4_GPUkernel_cpp1_ii_ad246568()      in GPUkernel.cu.o
  "___cudaRegisterFunction", referenced from:
      __sti____cudaRegisterAll_44_tmpxft_00000847_00000000_4_GPUkernel_cpp1_ii_ad246568()      in GPUkernel.cu.o
  "___cudaUnregisterFatBinary", referenced from:
      __cudaUnregisterBinaryUtil()      in GPUkernel.cu.o
  "_cudaLaunch", referenced from:
      cudaError cudaLaunch<char>(char*)in GPUkernel.cu.o
  "_cudaSetupArgument", referenced from:
      __device_stub__Z19calculateMandlebrotPiPfffffibff(int*, float*, float, float, float, float, int, bool, float, float)in GPUkernel.cu.o
  "_cudaMalloc", referenced from:
      cudaError cudaMalloc<int>(int**, unsigned long)in GPUkernel.cu.o
      cudaError cudaMalloc<float>(float**, unsigned long)in GPUkernel.cu.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ld: warning: ignoring file GPUkernel.cu.o, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libpng15.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_png_create_write_struct", referenced from:
      renderImage(int*, float*, int, int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, bool, int)in GPUfractal.cpp.o
  "_png_create_info_struct", referenced from:
      renderImage(int*, float*, int, int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, bool, int)in GPUfractal.cpp.o
  "_png_set_longjmp_fn", referenced from:
      renderImage(int*, float*, int, int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, bool, int)in GPUfractal.cpp.o
  "_png_init_io", referenced from:
      renderImage(int*, float*, int, int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, bool, int)in GPUfractal.cpp.o
  "_png_set_IHDR", referenced from:
      renderImage(int*, float*, int, int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, bool, int)in GPUfractal.cpp.o
  "_png_set_text", referenced from:
      renderImage(int*, float*, int, int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, bool, int)in GPUfractal.cpp.o
  "_png_write_info", referenced from:
      renderImage(int*, float*, int, int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, bool, int)in GPUfractal.cpp.o
  "_png_write_row", referenced from:
      renderImage(int*, float*, int, int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, bool, int)in GPUfractal.cpp.o
  "_png_write_end", referenced from:
      renderImage(int*, float*, int, int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, bool, int)in GPUfractal.cpp.o
  "_png_free_data", referenced from:
      renderImage(int*, float*, int, int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, bool, int)in GPUfractal.cpp.o
  "_png_destroy_write_struct", referenced from:
      renderImage(int*, float*, int, int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, bool, int)in GPUfractal.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/rw/344w_6js7d7dhg8pch7zws180000gn/T//ccZYSoRL.out (No such file or directory)
make: *** [base] Error 1
```

I have uploaded the latest version of the code to [github](https://github.com/tomnzed/GPUFractal), and you can also see the old (working) version of the code in the archive folder here (link removed because of noob user restrictions, but you can find it on github inside 'archive/0.1').

A little more info:
I had a similar issue with the undefined symbols in the first version of the code, but from plently of googling, found [this post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1253844) which fixed my problem by adding 
    `libpng-config --cflags --ldflags`
to the makefile

Thanks for reading this far, hopefully it wasn't too bad for a first post :)

And thanks for any help!

Comment: **Update: SOLVED** thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. From your suggestions, and working through the Makefiles that came with the CUDA sdk, I fixed the Makefile to compile correctly. I also had to add some proper function prototypes to get everything happy, and the result is it now works. If you're interested, [here's](http://imgur.com/0vEDg) what it's doing.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be building your host code for both 32-bit and 64-bit. On OS X, if you want to compile your host code (.cpp) for 64-bit, you need `-arch x86_64`, or if you want 32-bit, you need `-arch i386`, but I don't think you should specify both at once.

For your device code, if you want 64-bit, then you need to add `-m64` to the nvcc command line.  For 32-bit, use `-m32`.

You also need to link to the appropriate CUDA libraries (32-bit or 64-bit). If you look in the CUDA install path, you'll see that there are both 32-bit and 64-bit directories, with the appropriate libraries.  Include *only one* of these link paths (using `-L`), depending on whether you are building 32-bit or 64-bit. Then you must also link libcuda (`-lcuda`), and libcudart (`-lcudart`) if you are using the CUDA runtime API (likely).

You will also need to do the same for any other libraries (libpng or otherwise) that you link.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you need to link with the cuda library and cuda runtime library. The linker (g++) doesn't know about CUDA, so you need to tell it to link with the cuda libraries.

I had a mixed C++ and CUDA project where I used g++ to compile the C++ files and nvcc to compile my CUDA files. I then invoked

g++ -o exec_name *.o -lcuda -lcudart